# Print values from a dataframe based on null values on another column

Tags: r

I have two columns, col1 and col2. Col1 can have null values, but col2 can't
If col1 has null value, I want to select col2.

I tried this, where data is the dataframe example you see on the image below.

```
x <- data[is.na(data['col1']), c('col2')]
print(x)
```

I was expecting it to print the col2 (with 1440), but it prints

```
integer(0)
```

Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: It should be `is.na(data[['col1']])` with double braces. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but I think the dplyr function [`coalsesce`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) does what you are looking for:

> Given a set of vectors, coalesce() finds the first non-missing value at each position. It's inspired by the SQL COALESCE function which does the same thing for SQL NULLs.

For your example:

```
coalesce(data$col1, data$col2)
```

Would return col1 is non-null and col2 if col1 is null.